# How to add a parent key for JSON in a React app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, reactjs

I have a web application consisting of 2: Rails as a backend and React as a frontend. Data a user enters in html forms between is sent in JSON between the applications. The thing is that Rails expect JSON in a different format, for example:

```
{"user": {id: 1, name: "name1", age: 21}}
```

Where the React app sends it as follows:

```
{id: 1, name: "name1", age: 21}
```

And that goes for other models as well.

My approach is change the React app to send data with one additional key being the name of a model rather that change the Rails app. The thing is that I've inherited the React app and can't find a place where I can do that. I assume it should be easy. Where should I look for that?

Answer (score 0):

You should look for it in your React app wherever you're making an ajax call to post the form data. You should be able to just wrap the form data you have inside an object with the desired key before you post it.